# SQL Server 2008 left join where clause based on max date

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, join, where-clause

Got some help the other day on this and now really want to make a change for the better

Here is code

```
select 
    machines.serialnum, DRPS.assetnumber, DRPS.MOCALCSUM, DRPS.MICALCSUM,
    DRPS.COCALCSUM, DRPS.CICALCSUM, ISSUED.TotalIssued,
    REDEEMED.TotalRedeemed,drps.dropdate1,drps.dropdate2
from
    (select serialnum
     from machineinfo) as machines
LEFT JOIN 
    (select 
        assetnumber, min(dropdate) as [dropdate1], max(dropdate) as [dropdate2], 
        sum(mocalc) AS [MOCALCSUM], sum(micalc) AS [MICALCSUM],
        sum(cocalc) AS [COCALCSUM],sum(cicalc) AS [CICALCSUM]
     from drops
     where dropdate > '09/04/2012' and dropdate < dateadd(hour, -0, getdate())
     GROUP BY assetnumber) AS DRPS on machines.serialnum = drps.assetnumber
LEFT JOIN 
    (select 
        snissued, cast(sum(amount) as money) / 100 AS [TotalIssued] 
     from tickets
     where  dateissued > '09/04/2012' and dateissued < dateadd(hour, 0, getdate())
     group by snissued) AS ISSUED ON machines.serialnum = ISSUED.snissued
LEFT JOIN 
    (select 
         snredeemed, cast(sum(amount) as money) / 100 AS [TotalRedeemed] 
     from tickets
     where  dateredeemed > '09/04/2012' and dateredeemed < dateadd(hour, 0, getdate())
     group by snredeemed) AS REDEEMED ON machines.serialnum = REDEEMED.snredeemed
```

what I would like to accomplish if possible is for the second and third join is to use the `drps.drop1` in the where clause like this

```
where  dropdate > drps.dropdate1 and dropdate < drps.dropdate2
```

but it does not work

here is working output

```
    serialnum   MOCALCSUM   MICALCSUM   COCALCSUM   CICALCSUM   TotalIssued TotalRedeemed   dropdate1   dropdate2
0-2739-41401    5482    5498    132 148 3258.00 3110.00 2012-09-04 13:36:53.450 2012-09-05 13:55:38.750
0-2459-36182    1110    1054    114 58  1895.00 1657.00 2012-09-04 15:01:19.973 2012-09-05 13:55:38.967
```

end result is I need total issued and total redeemed  date range to be between the min and max date per serial number

Comment: just an addition on the first Left join would it be possible that if result is null then it could find the most recent before date as in there is no date between 9/4 and now so use 9/12/2012 since it was the last

Comment: When dealing with outer joins one should put all filters concerning outer table in join itself (ON clause) because otherwise null rows will not match the filter (except `is null` one) and be removed from result set. And you might want to add more meaningful description of problem than `but it does not work`. Things don't work in many different ways.

Comment: if i change    where  dateissued > '09/04/2012' and dateissued < dateadd(hour, 0, getdate()) to where  dateissued > drps.dropdate1 and dateissued < drps.dropdate2 then i get as a return The multi-part identifier "drps.dropdate2" could not be bound.

Comment: This is because you cannot use outer table in derived table. Anything you enclose in parentheses in `from` or `join` sections has no access to anything else in from or join. The only way to communicate is via ON clause. As you are aggregating data in derived table, there is no way to use filter in ON clause because it is too late. I think that you might nest last two joins so that you first filter un-aggregated data and aggregate it in outer join, repeating this for last left join to avoid duplications. Unfortunately a lot of writting.

Comment: Alternatively, reselect min and max from drops in last two left joins and use them as filter through inner join. Or simply use subqueries in select list - subquery is executed per row, so it can take outer expressions into consideration.

Comment: thanks which one of the selects in code above would i add the select to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @datebegin datetime
declare @dateend datetime
set @datebegin = '09/04/2012'
set @dateend = '09/08/2012'

select machines.serialnum,     DRPS.MOCALCSUM,DRPS.MICALCSUM,DRPS.COCALCSUM,DRPS.CICALCSUM,ISSUED.TotalIssued,
        REDEEMED.TotalRedeemed,drps.dropdate1,drps.dropdate2

from (select serialnum
    from machineinfo) as machines


LEFT JOIN (select assetnumber,min(dropdate)as [dropdate1], max(dropdate)as [dropdate2], sum(mocalc) AS [MOCALCSUM],sum(micalc) AS [MICALCSUM],
    sum(cocalc) AS [COCALCSUM],sum(cicalc) AS [CICALCSUM]
    from drops
    where  dropdate > @datebegin and dropdate < @dateend AND  (ignore is null)
            group by assetnumber) AS DRPS
    on machines.serialnum = drps.assetnumber
LEFT JOIN (select snissued,cast(sum(amount)as money)/100 AS [TotalIssued] from tickets
where  (dateissued > (select min(dropdate)
                        from drops 
                        where dropdate > @datebegin AND  (ignore is null) and snissued = assetnumber ))
                        and
       (dateissued < (select max(dropdate)
                        from drops 
                        where dropdate < @dateend AND  (ignore is null) and snissued = assetnumber))
group by snissued) AS ISSUED
ON machines.serialnum=ISSUED.snissued
LEFT JOIN (select snredeemed,cast(sum(amount)as money)/100 AS [TotalRedeemed]

from tickets
where  (dateredeemed > (select min(dropdate)
                        from drops 
                        where dropdate > @datebegin AND  (ignore is null)and snissued = assetnumber))
                        and
       (dateredeemed < (select max(dropdate)
                        from drops 
                        where dropdate < @dateend AND  (ignore is null)and snissued = assetnumber ))

group by snredeemed) AS REDEEMED
ON machines.serialnum=REDEEMED.snredeemed
order by REDEEMED.TotalRedeemed desc
```

based on the suggestion from comments i added the subquery into the selects and i am getting expected results now